# C++: Reference and Pointer question (example regarding OpenGL)

Tags: c++, pointers, opengl, reference, pass-by-reference

I would like to load textures, and then have them be used by multiple objects. Would this work?

```
class Sprite
{
    GLuint* mTextures; // do I need this to also be a reference?

    Sprite( GLuint* textures ) // do I need this to also be a reference?
    {
        mTextures = textures;
    }

    void Draw( textureNumber )
    {
        glBindTexture( GL_TEXTURE_2D, mTextures[ textureNumber ] );
        // drawing code
    }
};

// normally these variables would be inputed, but I did this for simplicity.
const int NUMBER_OF_TEXTURES = 40;
const int WHICH_TEXTURE = 10;

void main()
{
    std::vector<GLuint> the_textures;
    the_textures.resize( NUMBER_OF_TEXTURES );

    glGenTextures( NUMBER_OF_TEXTURES, &the_textures[0] );

    // texture loading code

    Sprite the_sprite( &the_textures[0] );
    the_sprite.Draw( WHICH_TEXTURE );
}
```

And is there a different way I should do this, even if it would work?

Thanks.

Comment: Just a note. If you're defining (vs declaring) something as a reference, it usually means something's wrong with your design.

Comment: @Falmarri, what do you mean? Are you suggesting that having a class field being a reference, or a local variable being a reference, is wrong?

Comment: @Kos: I'm talking about defining a class field as a reference.

Comment: Sounds like a natural way of implementiong any singular UML association endpoint which is known to be invariant through the whole lifetime of an object. Possible with a const pointer too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. yes, this *would* work
2. no need to make them be a reference: you store/pass a copy of a pointer (it's fast), and you don't plan to change this pointer outside
3. there're many different ways to do this, and the right one depends on your other code requirements.

e.g. you can use a global instance of textures:

textures.cpp:

```
static std::vector load_once_textures();
std::vector<GLuint> const& get_textures()
{
    static std::vector<GLuint> const the_textures = load_once_textures();
    return the_textures;
}

std::vector load_once_textures()
{
    // loading
}
```

textures.h

```
std::vector<GLuint> const& get_textures();
```

it's a simple approach and safe enough because textures will be loaded once and loading doesn't have a problem of static initialization order ambiguity

Answer (score 2):

That particular case should work. However, as soon as "the_textures" goes out of scope, then the pointer held by Sprite will become invalid. That would be the same, even if it was a reference.
In this, case, I suggest you put the std::vector<> inside the Sprite class instead, and have it owned and managed by that class instance.

Comment: yes, I realize the scope issue. but in this case it is in main(), so it will never go out of scope. as far as putting the `vector` inside the `Sprite` class, I would have to load the textures over again for every single sprite, which would be bad for performance. that is why I wanted to do something like my OP. however, would it work for the `Sprite` class to have a reference to the vector?

Comment: Your textures are only GLuint identifiers used by OpenGL, so copying the vector inside the Sprite object wouldn't load them again.

Comment: @tibur yes, I realize that. I thought Jon Watte meant not having any `vector` in main(), and instead doing it all in the `Sprite` class.

Comment: I assumed you use a texture loader module that just returns the same GLuint the second (and third...) time a given file name is loaded. Thus, the "loading" cost would be negligible. If you have 1,000 instances of the same sprite, an object templating system might be helpful. Main point: the code as written is legal. I just don't like dangling pointers in the general case.

Answer (score 0):

I am wondering why Draw cannot just take a reference to the object it is drawing.

```
class Sprite
{
public:

    Sprite()
    {
    }

    void Draw( GLuint & texture )
    {
        glBindTexture( GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture );
        // drawing code
    }
};
```

- Sprite is a type that does drawing in a specific way
- GLuint is a type that gets drawn

There could be polymorphism somewhere here in that:
- you have different draw algorithms
- there are polymorphic (virtual) methods in the different types of objects that get drawn

so Draw might be a virtual method and GLuint might be an abstract base class, in which case the actual vector will not be of the objects but of pointers to different types of the object.

You should certainly decouple out the way the objects are drawn from the way the objects are stored though, so storing a vector in the drawing class, or even passing in a pointer that assumes they are in some kind of array is not likely to be a good idea.

By the way, main should return int not void.

Comment: I need to store multiple textures in the `Sprite` class... as far `main()`, I know that it should return an `int`. but I wanted to keep the sample code as short as possible, and if I set the return type to `int`, then I would have had to add `return 0` at the end. or if I didn't somebody would tell me I forgot to return a value... haha

Answer (score 0):

Since the texture id doesn't change, what about using a `GLuint` value in `Sprite` instead of storing the array-ptr and choosing which sprite to draw?

Seems simpler, and no need to worry about scoping

This is unless you need to call glDeleteTextures before app-exit, then I suggest you create a TextureMgr class or something that solves this issue once and for all. ;)